# objective c: Unable to enable a publish_stream inside our application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ipad, session

I have an application that require a publish stream permission. I managed to use the openActionSessionWithReadPermission and open the Facebook session, but when calling the reauthorizedWithPublishPermission I have an error reading like this:

> error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error
>   2.)

This is the code I written to do the authorization process.

```
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_photos", nil]
                   allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                   completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                   switch (state)
                   {
                        case FBSessionStateCreated:
                        case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
                        case FBSessionStateOpen:
                             [[FBSession activeSession]  reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil]                                                                  defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                            [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                                state:state
                                                                                error:error
                                                                                success:success failure:failure];
                                                            }];
                                                        break;

                                                   }
                                                }];
```

I have a code that just use the openActiveSessionWithPublishPermission but still have the same result.

What does the error mean ?

Additionally, if I use openActiveSessionWithPublishPermission, and not passing publish_stream permission i can manage to open the session but under the app setting on Facebook website I won't see the option saying "This app can also -- Post on your behalf" settings. But if I add that on, same problem occur.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare permission like this

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_photos", @"publish_stream",nil]
```